# Winfo_x winfo_y get coordinates

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.3

I've get some problem.I need square to be bouncing off Canvas borders/
I need to get x and y of the square. How I can do it?

I know that I have to use `winfo_x` and `winfo_y`, bot I don't know how to use it.

```
from tkinter import*

root = Tk()
cnv = Canvas(root, bg='yellow', width=700, height=500)
cnv.pack()
rect = cnv.create_rectangle(50, 50, 100, 100, fill='black')

def paintloop():

    cnv.move(rect, 2, 2)
    root.after(10, paintloop)

root.after(0, paintloop)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the bounding-box of your rectangle by calling `cnv.bbox(rect)`. It will return a tuple of values `(x1, y1, x2, y2)` describing the area covered by rectangle. The
top left corner of the rectangle is (x1, y1) and the bottom right corner is (x2, y2).

Comment: thanks,also i've dound ,that it also legit to use cnv.coords(rect)

Comment: Yes, `cnv.coords(rect)` would work, too, but it's capable of doing other things depending on the arguments passed, so using it might be a bit slower than calling single purpose `cnv.bbox(rect)`.